# Display group header when there are no items in the group in a listview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to group my items in a list view (winform) with the group header showing the number of items in the group (including 0 item).
My problem is that, when I clear the items from the group or from the list view, the group header disappears.

How can I make sure the group headers don't disappear? I can't see any property to set in the ListView or ListViewGroup classes.

Thank you

Consider the code:

```
    ListViewGroup groupA;
    ListViewGroup groupB;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create group A and B and add them to the groups collection
        groupA = new ListViewGroup("A");
        listView1.Groups.Add(groupA);
        groupB = new ListViewGroup("B");
        listView1.Groups.Add(groupB);

        //Add 2 items in the list view and update the group headers
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("Item1", groupA));
        groupA.Header = "A - 1 item";

        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("Item2", groupB));
        groupB.Header = "B - 1 item";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear the items
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        //Update header
        //The problem here is that the headers are not displayed any more
        groupA.Header = "A - 0 item";
        groupB.Header = "B - 0 item";
    }
```

Comment: You will need some `dummy` items for reach group. It should be done carefully, to make it work smoothly and automatically, I think you need fairly much custom code (almost related to some events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am replying to my own question! It seems not possible to do it with the normal ListView. I have also looked at the underlying Win32 messages with no success. In the end, I gave up and I bought a third party control.